# How to Disable autocomplete in UITextView iPhone keyboard

Tags: iphone, autocomplete, keyboard

I am doing the application in which I want to disable the autocomplete feature of the keyboard in a textfield. How can I do this?

Comment: Don't let your question hanging here. accept one of the answers. the are both correct.

Answer (score 60):

Use epatel's method if you're using IB. If you're not using IB, then try the method

`-setAutoCorrectionType:`

and pass `UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo`

Comment: iOS autocorrect will also auto complete a word for you while you are typing it. Autocorrection and auto completion are controlled by the same behaviour called "auto correction". Also, this question is 9 years old. Move on, dude.

Answer (score 47):

In InterfaceBuilder you should set the `Text Input Trait` for Correction to `No`

[alt text http://img.skitch.com/20091231-e5fwp8yhm3jsmjdy2hgk8ewgac.jpg](http://img.skitch.com/20091231-e5fwp8yhm3jsmjdy2hgk8ewgac.jpg)